# Two-way communication on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I should make an application for Windows Phone 7.5, which is able to communicate bidirectionally with the same application installed on other devices with the same operating system.

I read that the Silverlight version on Windows Phone only supports BasicHttpBinding, so I think I will have to implement bi-directional mode using the BasicHttpBinding: for example, the node that accepts the incoming "connection" could send a GUID to the requesting node in order to identify a kind of session (this GUID should then be sent for each subsequent communication between two nodes).

Are there better alternatives?

The core of all communication is communication between two nodes:

- there are three types of requests (one of these must be very frequently, say every 10 seconds);
- the node which receives a request, could answer or ignore the request.

What is the impact on performance?

Comment: How are you dealing with routing?  Is this going to be a WiFi, local network thing or are you hoping for something that would work over the phone radio (GSM, etc)?

Comment: The communication takes place on the Internet (via WiFi, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to accept connections on WP7 devices, see [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/84014/506327.aspx).

Since WP7 doesn't support poll duplex WCF services either, I recommend you manually implement it, similar to this: http://www.dominikschmidt.net/2010/12/windows-phone-7-callbacks-and-duplex-wcf/

You will need a central server which all clients continually post messages to. Every time a Client1 calls the server, it checks the database to see if Client2 sent Client1 a message. If so, that message is included in the response to Client1.

Comment: Thanks for the links! From what I understand, now WP7 can not provide services, but can only consume them using BasicHttpBinding. Therefore, a device WP7 can "accept" the request from another device via a central server only...

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a relay service since it's unlikely you're going to have routable, stable communication directly between devices.  For example the [Project Hawaii Relay Service](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/services/) likely will provide what you want, or you could implement something that looks and acts a whole lot like it on your own server.